# Alternatives to partial mocking?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, coding-style

Tired of hand-crafting mocks, I am trying to introduce Mockito to my project.

Suppose I have a bunch of database accessors which isolate all Hibernate queries for given use case (or service). So I can have such interfaces as `RoutingDao`, `UserDao`, `ReportingDao`. Each of these interfaces extends a very generic `Dao` with methods such as `commit()`, `rollback()` or `reload(Entity)`. With Hibernate the latter is supposed to reload a detached entity with the current session. In tests, it should just return its argument.

With hand-crafted mocks it was easy: I had a `MockDao` with common implementation of this method, and `MockRoutingDao` would extend `MockDao` and use that implementation. One way I see with Mockito is to create `MockRoutingDao` that extends `MockDao` and delegates unmocked calls to it. The not-inherited methods would be mocked with a `spy()`. But this is pretty ugly - I still need to hand-craft a mock, and the whole idea of partial mocking & inheritance for reusing some implementation is a mess.

How can I improve it? **What are the best practices to create shared implementation for a mock method that can be reused accross many tests?**

Comment: @Griff Powermock is also a nifty tool

Comment: Powermock is for mocking statics and privates (it does this by invoking another classloader); it's used *in conjunction with* a mocking framework like Mockito or EasyMock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really want to write an org.mockito.stubbing.Answer implementation that handles common stuff every *DAO mock will handle.

You can still add custom `when` stubbing to this.